# CoroutineDispatcher on a Looper Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, realm, kotlin-coroutines

I have a helper class for doing some jobs on database Realm. As you know, we have some restriction in working with realm, such as:

1. Realm instance is not auto refresh on non looping thread.
2. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created

My Helper class extends  `CoroutineScope` and to provide a `CoroutineContext` I used this code
`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()`

But my problem is all jobs on this `CoroutineScope` is running on non looping thread so
How can I create a `ExecutorCoroutineDispatcher` which is run on a single looper thread.

It's obvious I don't want to use `Dispatchers.Main` because it supposes to do jobs on my Database

Comment: How about create a `val handlerThread = HandlerThread(name)`, start it then create handler on top of its looper and transform it into dispatcher: `Handler(handlerThread.looper).asCoroutineDispatcher()`

Comment: @Pawel
I alread test this but it throws this exception

  `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.os.MessageQueue android.os.Looper.mQueue' on a null object reference`

Comment: Sorry you are right. I hadn't start the handler thread.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although the OP's problem has already solved by @Pawel's comment, for someone who may need a certain code snippet:

```
// prepare a HandlerThread and start it
val handlerThread = HandlerThread("MyThread")
handlerThread.start()
// obtain Handler from the HandlerThread's looper
val handler = Handler(handlerThread.looper)
// Now you can get CoroutineDispatcher from the Handler
val myDispatcher = handler.asCoroutineDispatcher()
```

Or shortly using Scope functions:

```
val myDispatcher = HandlerThread("MyThread")
    .apply { start() }
    .looper.let { Handler(it) }
    .asCoroutineDispatcher()
```

Comment: Is it necessary to somehow stop the thread when it is not needed anymore, to prevent memory leaks?

Comment: @VladimirKattsyn I didn't notice that previously, however it likely is. cf. [File descriptor leak — HandlerThread](https://medium.com/@ansgar/caveat-of-handlerthread-d3d1d6048d83).